# How can I speed up my n*n sudoku grid generator?

Tags: java, sudoku

This is my code for a Sudoku-style grid generator. It generates every possible different n*n grid where there cannot be the same number in a certain column or row (like a sudoku) and also counts how many different combinations there are. E.g. one example of a 3*3 grid could be:

[ 3, 2, 1 ]

[ 1, 3, 2 ]

[ 2, 1, 3 ]

Unfortunately, for anything past 4*4 grids, it takes too long to do this, therefore, could anybody help me edit this slightly so that it is much faster?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GridN {

public static final int SIZE = 3;

public static int count;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] grid = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    count = 0;
    bruteSolve(0, 0, grid);
}

public static void bruteSolve(int num1, int num2, int[][] grid) {
    for (int i = 1; i < SIZE + 1; i++) {
        grid[num1][num2] = i;
        if (num2 == SIZE - 1 && num1 == SIZE - 1) {
            if (isValid(grid)) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(grid));
                System.out.println(count);
            }
        } else if (num2 == SIZE - 1) {
            bruteSolve(num1 + 1, 0, grid);
        } else {
            bruteSolve(num1, num2 + 1, grid);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean isValid(int[][] grid) {
    int factorial = 1;
    int fibonacci = 0;
    int totalX1 = 1;
    int totalY1 = 1;
    int totalX2 = 0;
    int totalY2 = 0;

    for (int i = SIZE; i > 0; i--) {
        factorial = factorial * i;
    }
    for (int i = SIZE; i > 0; i--) {
        fibonacci = fibonacci + i;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            totalY1 = totalY1 * grid[i][j]; // checks all columns
            totalX1 = totalX1 * grid[j][i]; // checks all rows
            totalX2 = totalX2 + grid[j][i];
            totalY2 = totalY2 + grid[i][j];
        }
        if (totalX1 != factorial || totalY1 != factorial
                || totalX2 != fibonacci || totalY2 != fibonacci) {
            return false;
        }
        totalX1 = 1;
        totalY1 = 1;
        totalX2 = 0;
        totalY2 = 0;
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by speeding up? The number of possible [magic squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square) grows enormously with the size of the square. You probably have to give up this brute-force approach, and try to generate only some, but not all possible squares.

Comment: For questions about improving existing, functioning code, visit the [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) But be sure you ask your question in such a way that it remains [on-topic](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In other words: are building a sudoku generator, or are you doing something else, where you actually need all possible magic squares?

Comment: Me again. According to Wikipedia, it's *not even known* how many different magic squares there are for squares with size 6×6 and larger...